# External API link is broken and I can not get any data from bad API's in Json file in iOS development

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to make an API call and was given three links at which I need to reference as end points but both of these links are broken or return no values.

Comment: As the other answer suggests, `CATEGORY` and `MEAL_ID` are placeholders and you're supposed to replace these withe actual value of a category or a meal id. This is not an iOS problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "External API link is broken", "bad links or return Null values". Please show specific code and describe the exact error behavior you are observing. Currently, your question really misses specific details and is in danger of being closed.

Comment: Please Delete this question thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unlikely that your issue has anything to do with iOS.

If I follow your first "End point" it returns a json formatted string of "categories"

If I then take the first Category "Beef" and call:

```
https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?c=Beef
```

it returns a json formatted string of "meals"

If I then take the first Meal ID "52874" and call:

```
https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/lookup.php?i=52874
```

it returns a json formatted string for the "Beef and Mustard Pie" meal.

Comment: I don't know.. does that code run for you, and return the expected data?